# cocos2d - child already added. It can't be added again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

so I created a pause menu,

```
- (void) reset {

    CCSprite * backg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"noise.png"];
    backg.position = ccp(480/2, 320/2); 
    [pauseMenu addChild:backg];


    CCLabelBMFont *restartLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Restart" fntFile:@"good_dog_plain_32.fnt"];
    restartLabel.color = ccc3(68,136,168);
    CCMenuItemLabel *restartItem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:restartLabel target:self selector:@selector(restartMenu)];
    restartItem.position = ccp(0, 40);

    CCLabelBMFont *mainMenuLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Main Menu" fntFile:@"good_dog_plain_32.fnt"];
    mainMenuLabel.color = ccc3(68,136,168);
    CCMenuItemLabel *mainMenuItem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:mainMenuLabel target:self selector:@selector(exitMenu)];
    mainMenuItem.position = ccp(0, -40);

    CCLabelBMFont *resumeLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Resume" fntFile:@"good_dog_plain_32.fnt"];
    resumeLabel.color = ccc3(68,136,168);
    CCMenuItemLabel *resumeItem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:resumeLabel target:self selector:@selector(resumeMenu)];


    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:resumeItem,restartItem,mainMenuItem, nil];
    menu.position = ccp(480/2,320/2);
    [pauseMenu addChild:menu z:1];


    [self.hero sleep];

    [self addChild:pauseMenu];

}
```

this menu is created in my gamescene, so whenever a user pressed the pause button this shows up, now I have another scene called `mainMenu` and you can go to `mainMenu` from the pause menu and I used this code :

```
- (void) exitMenu {

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[mainMenu scene]];
}
```

so once you press this button it works and goes back to the main menu, but then when I press the "play" button from the `mainMenu` and go to the game and press the pause button I get this error :  `child already added. It can't be added again` ... this doesnt happen if I restart the game scene from the pause menu, only happens when I go to the game from the main menu after the game is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because it calls `[self addChild:pauseMenu];` every time you hit the pause button. You can try this instead:

```
int pauseMenuTag = 99;

if(![self getChildByTag:pauseMenuTag]) {
    [self addChild:pauseMenu z:0 tag:pauseMenuTag];
}
```

Which will hopefully check if you've already added the node. Alternatively, you can make sure all the methods that the buttons call remove the pause menu with `removeChild:cleanup:`

Comment: I will upvote this comment, because I was looking to do this and it is very helpful, but the problem was that in `exitMenu` function I didnt remove the pauseMenu child, so when the game ran again, the child was already there. your solution would fix it and so would just removing the child.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error happened when I was creating scene with missing json file:

```
var loginScene = ccs.load(res.MainScene_json);
```

I deleted MainScene_json file, thats why it was giving me this error. When I properly referenced the right file **Login_json**, the error was gone.

```
var loginScene = ccs.load(res.Login_json);
```